# Получение транзакции Ethereum Classic через web3 js

Tags: ethereum

Для ETH получаем транзакцию так:

```
const trx = await this.web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash);
```

И все с этим хорошо. Но для ETC это не проходит, выбрасывает ошибку:

```
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"Action not found.","id":4}
```

Помогите пжлст, как получить транзакцию для Ethereum Classic?

Конфиг такой:

```
ethereum_classic: {
    mainnet: {
        provider: "https://blockscout.com/etc/mainnet/api/eth-rpc",
        options: {
            chainId: 1,
            gasPrice: 20 * 1000000000,
            gasAmountToSend: 50 * 1000,
        },
    },
    testnet: {
        provider: "https://blockscout.com/etc/kotti/api/eth-rpc",
        options: {
            chainId: 1,
            gasAmountToSend: 50 * 1000,
        },
    },
    derivationPath: "m/44'/61'/0'/0",
},
```

Comment: А хэш транзакции - разный для ETH и ETC, или Вы спрашиваете у разных блкчейнов "найди транзакцию по такому то хешу" и даёте им на вход один и тот же хэш?

Comment: Хэш, конечно же, разный.

Answer (score 1):

Решил эту проблему отправкой прямого запроса к
API провайдера (без web3):

```
Get transaction info.
https://blockscout.com/etc/mainnet/api?module=transaction&action=gettxinfo&txhash={transactionHash}
```

Comment: Хорошо, что проблема решилась! я, откровенно говоря, так и не понял, что делает web3 :-)